# What are some types of red wine that aren't buttery or sweet-ish?

Tags: wine, red-wine

I'm just getting into wine, and I've tried some red wines, but nothing I particularly liked.

I found a few pinot noirs too sweet, and last night I had a Paso Robles cabernet sauvignon that was a bit too buttery and smooth for me.

What should I look into for wines that are more, I guess, acidic and have an edge to them?  I don't need anything particularly bitter, but butteriness and sweetness do put me off.

Comment: Buttery is not a term I’ve ever heard applied to red wines. Very few cabs are sweet at all.

Comment: When you say sweet, might you be referring to specific fruit notes rather than actual residual sugar?   This is a common point where I see confusion in red wine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What are some types of red wine that aren't buttery or sweetish?**

My guess is that one could try a [red wine](https://www.thewinebuyingguide.com/Wine-101/Red-Wine-Sweetness-Chart) like **Merlot, Cabernet Sauvignon, and Pinot Noir**. Generally speaking they are dry and thus not sweet.

[image]

[**Red Wine Sweetness Chart**](https://www.thewinebuyingguide.com/Wine-101/Red-Wine-Sweetness-Chart)

Some Chardonnays may in fact be buttery, but not all.

> [**What does the term “buttery” mean in reference to wine?**](https://www.winespectator.com/articles/what-is-a-buttery-wine-53333)
>
> "Buttery" can refer to a flavor, smell, texture or some combination of all three, and it's most commonly associated with Chardonnay. Buttery flavors usually come from diacetyl, an organic compound that’s a natural byproduct of fermentation. Diacetyl can also be a result of putting a wine through a malolactic conversion. Exposing a wine to oak barrels can also emphasize buttery notes—both from the toasting on the inside of the barrel, and the softening effect barrels can have on a wine’s texture.
>
> Have you ever smelled a wine and it’s a dead ringer for butter-flavored popcorn? That’s not a coincidence. Diacetyl is sometimes added to foods for its buttery flavor—think movie-theater popcorn, margarine, crackers and cooking oil.
>
> I consider “buttery” a positive note. Just like any other wine characteristic, I prefer it in balance with a wine’s other elements. But buttery Chardonnays used to be very fashionable, and now much less so. These days, sometimes “buttery” is used as a pejorative term.
>
> Other descriptors in a similar vein are cream/creamy, piecrust, caramel, butterscotch or brioche.

Comment: Nice chart +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Very few red wines are actually sweet. Meiomi pinot noir is slightly off dry, but hardly sweet. I've never had a sweet cabernet sauvignon. Buttery is an adjective sometimes associated with California chardonnay which has gone through malolactic conversion. Lots of people seem to like it although I'm not a fan. [Here is a good article](https://www.winespectator.com/articles/if-red-wines-undergo-malolactic-fermentation-why-aren-t-they-buttery).

If you have a good wine store, I'd suggest asking the shop keeper for suggestions. Personally I like Spanish wines like Rioja which are good values. You can also look for wines with higher alcohol content. It is hard to imagine getting to 13%+ ABV while maintaining any residual sweetness.

Comment: Eric S's recommendation of Rioja is a good one. The chief grape in Rioja is Tempranillo, and there are a number of good American ones.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, red wines are never sweet (with a few exceptions like Recioto) - so you probably mean the wines are full because the grapes were quite ripe, typically from a sunny location.

As a European, I often find American, Australian and similar wines more full and 'friendly', but lacking in acid that would make it pair better with food.

Look for wines from colder climates; e.g. European wines from Austria, Northern Italy, sub-Alpine France or similar non-European versions.